# Browser crashes when navigates to the custom SPList

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splist

My Browser crashes when navigates to the custom `SPList` I created for the purpose of custom form and its validations.

Am stuck with why this happens. Till two days before the custom form was working correctly, suddenly from yesterday onwards, the form's few columns were vanished.

So I created another splist from the old one's template and gave another name. Now when I navigate to the splist my browser crashes!

I am using SP 2010 Enterprise Edition.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing much to go on here. The best advice is to see if its just the browser first.

1) is its IE only?

2) did you test in 64 and 32 bit versions of ie?

3) does it work on other machines.

these questions will determin if its specific browser related, if its related to that pc only or somthing that you have changed in code somewhere if it doesnt work on any.

Comment: Its working correctly on Chrome Browser. Only IE has issues.I just observed this.

Comment: ok, what version of ie and what build? are you using ie 11, 64 or 32? so we need to narrow it down. would it be possible to test if its only that computer?

Comment: am using IE 10. The strange thing is that, i used the same browser few weeks back and tested  everything fine.I have some 70+ fields in my custom list form, which is created  using SP D,added  5+ JavaScript files for  validation, included SPServices js code for page_onload functionality. Suddenly this browser starts behaving in a strange way.

Comment: My OS is 64 bit Win 7 Enterprise. so i think, its 64 bit of IE 10 Browser.Let me try with other systems' IE browser  which are different config.